# How to bind "rest" variables to list of values in macro in Scheme

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I want to make a helper macro for writing match-extensions. I have something like this:

```
(define-match-expander my-expander
  (λ (stx)
    (let* ([dat (cdr (syntax-e stx))]
           [var1 (car dat))]
           [var2 (cadr dat)])
      ;transformer goes here )))
```

So I wanted a macro that will do this let binding. I've started with something like this:

```
(define-syntax-rule (define-my-expander (id vars ...) body)
  (define-match-expander id
    (λ (stx)
      (match-let ([(vars ...) (cdr (syntax-e stx))])
        body))))
```

but `match-let` isn't defined in transformation time.

First question would be is there any other way of doing this (making this expanders, I mean)? Maybe there is already something similar in plt-scheme that I'm not aware of, or I'm doing it wrong in some way.

Regardless of answer on the first question, if I ever want to bound list of variables to list of values inside of a macro, how should I do it?

EDIT: In combination with Eli's answer macro now looks like this:

```
(define-syntax-rule (define-my-expander (id vars ...) body)
  (define-match-expander id
    (λ (stx)
      (syntax-case stx ()
        [(_ vars ...)
         body]))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what it is that you're trying to achieve, but my guess is that this goes in the right direction:

```
(define-match-expander my-expander
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ (var1 var2) stuff ...)
       ;; use #'var1 #'var2 and #'(stuff ...) here
       ])))
```

The thing is that `syntax-e` is used to "unwrap" a syntax object and give you what it holds -- but the actual content may surprise you.  For example, `(foo . (bar))` will have a little different contents than `(foo bar)`.  So generally speaking, using `syntax-case` to do the pattern matching for you is *much* easier.  In addition to being easier, it will also give some sensible error messages when there are errors, instead of what you'd get with your code.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful and helped me solve my problem. For a completeness sake, if I was not making expanders, but say, macro that expands into something that has lambda that takes a list and I want to bind list elements to macro params?

Comment: It most cases when you write macros using pattern matching works.  But every once in a while (perhaps more frequently when you write more advanced macros with issues like good error messages) you need to turn them into a list.  For this, you can use something like `(syntax->list #'(stuff ...))` -- it takes the parenthesized syntax object, and turns it into a list of syntax objects.